# Find non-duplicate value in one column based on known value of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given the following table ManagerRepRelationship:

```
repId  managerId
 35       33
 36       33
 37       33
 23       56
 26       60
 35       34
 37       34
```

As you can see, manager 33 and manager 34 both share representatives 35 and 37. If I have **only** the known value of manager 33:

```
SELECT repId FROM ManagerRepRelationship WHERE managerId=33
```

I'll get back 35,36,37.

My question here is, based on only knowing that managerId, is there any way to see if the repId's given back have no other duplicate value in that repId column throughout the table.

So in the above statement I want to find the rep that only has ONE relationship. So in this case, repId 36 would be the return I would want because 33 is the only manager for that rep.

Can this be done in one SQL statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to reference that same table again in a subquery to check for your other condition:

```
SELECT repId FROM ManagerRepRelationship a WHERE managerId=33
AND not exists (SELECT 1 FROM ManagerRepRelationship b WHERE b.repId = a.repId and b.managerId <> a.managerId)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [repId] TINYINT
   ,[managerId] TINYINT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([repId], [managerId])
VALUES (35, 33)  
      ,(36, 33)  
      ,(37, 33)  
      ,(23, 56)  
      ,(26, 60)  
      ,(35, 34)  
      ,(37, 34);

SELECT DS1.*
FROM  @DataSource DS1
LEFT JOIN @DataSource DS2
    ON DS1.[repID] = DS2.[repId]
    AND DS2.[managerId] <> 33
WHERE DS1.[managerId] = 33
    AND DS2.[repId] IS NULL;
```

Comment: Revising my comment... I see that much of the complexity you posted was setup rather than answer.  I stand by my -1 for an unclear answer, though.

Comment: Originally misread your answer due to the unnecessary setup code.  I've edited my comment accordingly.  You do see that you posted DML plus multiple queries, right?  You wonder why that's confusing?

Comment: It is a full working (tested) example, which can be easily tested. I am sorry if declaring a table variable and inserting few rows is complex for you, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You have to group the rep_id and then count.

```
SELECT repId FROM ManagerRepRelationship WHERE 
repId IN (SELECT repId FROM ManagerRepRelationship WHERE managerId=33)
GROUP BY repId
HAVING COUNT(repId) = 1
```

(not tested)

Comment: Won't work.  `WHERE` applies before `GROUP BY`, so records with `managerId!=33` are excluded from the `COUNT`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do it.  Here's one:

```
select m33.repId
  from           ManagerRepRelationship m33
       left join ManagerRepRelationship mOther
              on m33.repId = mOther.repId
             and mOther.managerId != m33.managerId
 where m33.managerId = 33
   and mOther.repId is NULL
```